# Acessing Post Rest Api using Power query

Tags: post, powerbi, powerquery

I am new to power BI and power query, I am trying to get the JSon data from Post rest api. But i always get a 400 error. Where am I going wrong.

```
let
 authkey ="Bearer xxxx",
 url = "https://example.com/xxx",
 body = "{""objectId"":""settlement_entity"",""queryString"":""?itemrefs=settlementreference,itemdescription&perpage=12&includekeyitems=true&includeforeignkeyitems=true&includetimestamp=true&includeadditionalmeta=true""}",
 Source  = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,
     [
         Headers = [#"Authorization"= authkey,#"Content-Type"="application/json"], Content = Text.ToBinary(body)
     ]
 ))
in
Source
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed the issue the body was missing square bracket

```
let
 authkey ="Bearer xxxx",
 url = "https://example.com/xxx",
 body = "[{""objectId"":""settlement_entity"",""queryString"":""?itemrefs=settlementreference,itemdescription&perpage=12&includekeyitems=true&includeforeignkeyitems=true&includetimestamp=true&includeadditionalmeta=true""]}",
 Source  = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,
     [
         Headers = [#"Authorization"= authkey,#"Content-Type"="application/json"], Content = Text.ToBinary(body)
     ]
 ))
in
Source
```